# Why Firefox keeps removing 1px to the table cell's border?

Tags: html, css, firefox, html-table

Is there any reason Firefox is removing 1px the the border's value as I define in the CSS file?

```
.aprovGriditem th
{
   border-collapse: collapse;
   border: 4px solid #BBC6E3;
   padding: 0;
}
```

## EDIT

```
<table cellpadding="0"  cellspacing = "1" runat="server" id="tblEmployees" width="100%">
 <tr id="tr1" runat="server" class="aprovGriditem">
   <td>
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server">
   </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

When I check firebug, I see the border's value is **3**. When I set the value to **3**, I get **2**.  And how to deal with that?

Comment: @radio. I put the all rule and I'm not using a rest css

Comment: By the way, Chrome and IE9 are displaying correctly.

Comment: are you using border-collapse? check out this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1035706/firefox-1-pixel-bug-with-border-collapse-workaround

Comment: Yes, look the question, I've posted the entire rule. Also, I'm using cellspacing = "0" because cells need to be spaced from each other. Any way, removing cellspacing = "0" is not solving the problem. FF is still removing 1px from the border's value.

Comment: @Richard77 The HTML code, too, please.

Comment: @Richard77 I'm not able to replicate the issue: http://jsfiddle.net/mQxuz/ I've tested in Firefox.

Comment: Looking @ŠimeVidas jsFiddle in Chrome/IE8/FF ... I don't see any difference

Comment: When I look at it in Firebug i get: 
`border-top-width 4px
border-right-width 4px
border-bottom-width 4px
border-left-width 4px`
 -> Maybe update your FF?

Comment: !DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"

Comment: What version of firefox/what platform

Comment: Firefox 15.0.1 Windows 7

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a grand explanation but in testing with the fiddle it seems firefox reacts differently than other browsers when the border-collapse is placed on only one element type within the table. Move the border-collapse to the entire table:

```
#tblEmployees{
   border-collapse:collapse;
}
.aprovGriditem th
{
   border: 4px solid #BBC6E3;
   padding: 0;
}
```