# Removing a tr having all td's with border making issues to other tr in mozilla

Tags: jquery, border-layout

I have a table having id `agenda_tbl` which is in the form of ajax response. The row of this table are created from  while loop.

```
<table id="agenda_tbl">
<thead>......</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr>
     <td>Data1</td>
     <td>Data2</td>
     <td>Data3</td>
     <td>Data3</td>
     <td><input type="button" class="approve_btn"</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  .........
 </tr>
</table>
```

CSS for the above table

```
#agenda_tbl
{
margin-top:5px;
border-collapse: collapse;
font-size: 12px;
}
#agenda_tbl td
{
border:1px solid black;
padding:3px;
 }
```

I have written click event for the button in the first page.When I click the button,I need to hide the current row completely.I have done this with following jquery.

```
$(document).on('click','.approve_btn',function(e)
{
    var element = $(this);
    if(confirm('Do you approve this agenda?'))
    {
       element.closest('tr').remove();
    //this hides the current row.Also used hide(),made html() of row 
     //to empty.But doesnt work
    }

});
```

This script works properly for me,but the border for the adjacent rows are missing.I have googled a lot,but couldn't found a solution.

Screen shot1
[image: screen shot1]
After clicking approve button of any row,adjacent rows lost their border.
[image: screen shot2]

Comment: In what browser? I have this fiddle in Chrome not showing your issue: http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/4Lubz94u/

Comment: in mozilla.lemme check this in chrome @mplungjan

Comment: In FX 31v I get a thicker border in some cases

Comment: In chrome its working perfectly.lemme update firefox.How to remove the thicker frame??

Comment: @mplungjan my mozila is 40.0.0,latest

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1035706/firefox-1-pixel-bug-with-border-collapse-workaround

Comment: @mplungjan have you checked in mozilla 40.0..0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. I know the border is thicker but it seems to have solved the known FX 1px row bug - at least in Fx 31 which is what I have here

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/4Lubz94u/)

```
#agenda_tbl {
    margin-top:5px;
    border-spacing: 0; 
/* when removing the following line, 
   the lines may be thick but it works in OSX FX 40.0.3  
   even with 1px border */
    border-collapse: collapse; 
    font-size: 12px;
}
#agenda_tbl td {
    padding:3px;
    border:2px solid black;
}
```

Comment: This is not working for me in mozilla 40.0..0.Its working in chrome perfectly

Comment: Weird. Then I am sorry.

Comment: WHen I removed border-collapse,its working in mozilla also.But the  border is thick

Comment: Right... Sorry. Vote for the bug to be fixed