# Align table header to other table body in firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox

I have a css problem when using **Firefox** and I don't know where is it exactly.

I have 1 table that is built from 2 tables, it uses one table's `Thead` and populates the second table `tbody` and then it looks like 1 table with Fix Header, everything worked fine until FireFox ruined the party.

I view the table strange in **Firefox**:
[image]
And this is how the last `TH` element(Last activated) looks in FireBug:
[image]

In **Chrome** it looks ok:
[image]
And this is how the last `TH` looks in Chrome:
[image]

Html:

```
<div class="modal-scrollable-table-wrapper">
                            <table style="border-left:0">
                                <thead class="fixed-header active-rules" data-table="activeRulesTable">
                                    <tr>
                                        <th data-sort="0">Status</th>
                                        <th data-sort="1">Name</th>
                                        <th data-sort="2">Action</th>
                                        <th data-sort="3">Condition</th>
                                        <th data-sort="4">Last activated</th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                            </table>

                            <div class="modal-scrollable-table-body">
                                <table id="activeRulesTable" class="cell-border">
                                    <thead style="display: none">
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody>
                    //get the rows from the server and populates using js
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

CSS:

```
html {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

*, *:before, *:after {
    -webkit-box-sizing: inherit;
    -moz-box-sizing: inherit;
    box-sizing: inherit;
}
table, thead, th, td {
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}


.modal .modal-scrollable-table-wrapper table {
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 902px;
}

#activeRulesTable {
    border-top: 0;
}

.modal .modal-scrollable-table-wrapper td {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 12px;
    background: transparent;
    padding: 8px 5px;
    color: #6b6b6b;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}


.modal .modal-scrollable-table-wrapper th {
    background: #f8f8f8;
    /*border: 1px solid #c6c6c6;*/
    /*border-bottom: none;*/
    vertical-align: middle;
    color: #46aaf6;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 13px;
    padding: 8px 5px;
}

.modal .modal-scrollable-table-wrapper tr > :nth-child(1) {
    width: 62px;
}

.modal .modal-scrollable-table-wrapper tr > :nth-child(2) {
    width: 169px;
}

.modal .modal-scrollable-table-wrapper tr > :nth-child(3) {
    width: 205.5px;
}

.modal .modal-scrollable-table-wrapper tr > :nth-child(4) {
    width: 332px;
}

.modal .modal-scrollable-table-wrapper tr > :nth-child(5) {
    width: 78px;
}

.modal#automated-rules-log-modal tr > th,
.modal#automated-rules-log-modal tr > td {
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.scroll tr {
    display: flex;
    /*border-width: 0 0 0 0;*/
}

.scroll tbody {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    overflow-y: auto;
    height: 300px;
}

#activeRulesTable th {
    border-top-width: 1px;
    border-right-width: 0;
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 30px;
}

    #activeRulesTable th:last-of-type {
        border-right-width: 1px;
        line-height: 18px;
    }
```

**EDIT:**
I found a better solution in this question:[firefox 1 pixel bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1035706/firefox-1-pixel-bug-with-border-collapse-workaround)
I used `border-spacing = 0` instead of `border-collapse` and it works fine.

Comment: Perhaps you should think about using a css reset. if that doesn't fix it, at least it should make it easier to fix. Ex: http://cssreset.com/scripts/eric-meyer-reset-css/

Comment: I tried, but it didn't help me.

Comment: Send link to review

Comment: I run your code and it doesn't render the same as your screenshots. Could you provide full code or url of your website?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this with the code you provide. You should make a jsFiddle or an inline example inside your question.

Comment: [Here is a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/j3983rkv/) - there is no visible difference. You need to provide us with more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found some redundant borders in your CSS:

```
table, thead, th, td {
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

Bordering only td and th gives the same effect.

Also, your "heading" table has a style attribute `style="border-left:0"`
When I disabled border-collapse I found that TD and TH elements have a slightly different width, so the problem may be caused by the difference between browser's border-collapsing algorithms.

Try to remove `style="border-left:0"` and split the above rule in two:

```
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
td, th {
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
}
```

Comment: That's what I suspected, when I disabled the border-collapse the problem was gone, but when enabling it again there is a difference between the way the border was calculated between the header and the body. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

I'm thinking that your 0.5px is causing the problem:

```
.modal .modal-scrollable-table-wrapper tr > :nth-child(3) {
    width: 205.5px; /* change this to 205 or 206 */
}
```

Reason being that each browser calculates decimal pixels differently from others. In general, using a non-integer pixel value set in CSS confuses browsers, because they have to round up/down. You can see an example of this here:

http://cruft.io/static/rounding/
(Try testing this in different browsers and see how they return different widths)

Comment: good thinking! guess this too fall into the `sub-pixel problems` - might help reading [**this thread**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39209886/1px-calculation-issue-with-browsers) too....

Comment: @OffirPe'er it'd be better if you could create a fiddle / snippet showing the problem so that it the issue can be replicated and checked....